# Selenium Java: Unable to get handle to popup

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not sure if getWindowHandles is the right way to get the handle of a popup because the following is returning only the parent handle and not the child handle.

```
for (String handle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
            driver.switchTo().window(handle);
}
WebDriverWait waitforEle = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
waitforEle.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy
(By.xpath("//*[@id='blah']")));
```

Could anyone tell me how to handle a popup if the above way is incorrect?

Thanks,
Tickbox.

Comment: You can see if that pop-up is an alert then by doing following:  `Alert alert =driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();`if not then please post some html code or a URL

Comment: @kushalツ You can see if the popup is an alert by right-clicking on it. If a context menu shows up like it's an HTML page, then it's HTML and not a JS alert.

Comment: Yup, @Tickbox mightn't have been aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

**getWindowHandles()** method gives you the IDs of opened browser windows or tabs. You just need to wait for one WebElement with the locator of the popup.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='blah']"));
```

Comment: But its not a browser window or a tab. Its a div popup.

Comment: And that's what I'm talking about. You don't need a getWindowHandles(), just wait for presence of element with locator of your popup.

Comment: Probably wait should work, even so you can check in chrome's console section by using `$x"//*[@id='blah']"` and enter to check if the element appears then is part of the same html page o/w is part of some `iframe`

Comment: No it doesn't work. I also tried to check if its part of an iframe. No luck

Answer (score 0):

If the popup is alert then use:

```
Alert alert =driver.switchTo().alert(); alert.accept();
```

or if it is application popup then use:

```
String parentWinHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
//Click the button or link which populates the window
driver.findElement(By.id(actionBtn)).click();
Thread.sleep(5000);
Set<?> popupHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
//SOP *popupHandles* 
Iterator<?> iterator = popupHandles.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext())
    {
    String popupHandle = iterator.next().toString();
    if(!popupHandle.contains(parentWinHandle)) {
        driver.switchTo().window(popupHandle);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        //Perform the operation you want to do
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWinHandle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, don't recommend anybody to use Thread class, if you need to wait. It is much better to use WebDriverWait class for those needs.

Comment: @SanchelliosProg I Agree, using `Thread.sleep();` is not good practice.

Comment: But the scenario in my Test Case was different where I had to wait for 5 seconds, during which screen performs countdown of five seconds. My Bad that I had posted it without removing.

Comment: No sorry its definitely not an alert.

Comment: @Tickbox can you try using the 2nd part of code that I posted (if it is application popup)

Comment: Although its a popup I am still able to access it directly without switching. Thanks for your help!